# AngularFire - Firebase - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I've just started a new project using angular cli.

I have set up my firebase config in an environments fire.

I initialise the app in my app module but I get the following error:

> Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

**App Module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


// AngularFire and Firestore
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

// Routing
import { AppRouting } from './routing/app-routing';

// Environment
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

// Components
import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';


 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase), 
  AngularFirestoreModule,
  AppRouting,
  LoginModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My login component displays, but when I try to call 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' I receive the error.

**Login Component**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

...

createAccount(){
 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log(errorCode + ' / ' + errorMessage);
  // ...
 });
}
```

I've used the same setup in a previous project which is running on an older cli version. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: I don't recommend using AngularFire. It's just another package that you have to be worried about updating and compatibility. Firebase node package itself can do all functions that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login Component you’re not using angularfire2 which you initialized. You didn’t initialize the standard Firebase sdk

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md

Comment: Thanks Troels. I added import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'; to the top of my component. I then received an error stating there was no provider. So I added AngularFireAuth to my login.module providers and the error has gone away. Is that correct? The only error I get now is that when I try to use my login component it reads: auth/network-request-failed / A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

Comment: This only seems to be happening on chrome.